# How to remove or override a compilation flag from a cmake subproject

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the [Nlhomann JSON](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) library as a sub-project in a subdirectory in my `CMake`-based parent project. The library is referenced by my `CMakeLists.txt` which is essentially defined as below. The problem is that when building the whole project this library somehow adds an unwanted `-std=gnu++11` compiler flag *after* my already specified `-std=c++2a` flag. This addition makes the compilation to fail as my source code requires the latter.

Do you know how to modify my CMakeLists.txt in order to:

1. remove this specific flag specified in the `json` sub-project
2. force the compilation of the sub-project to use the C++ standard I want

An answer to either one is okay, but if you can answer both, that would be much appreciated.

```
# CMakeLists.txt

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
add_compile_options(-std=c++2a) # repetitive probably

set(JSON_Install OFF CACHE INTERNAL "") # disable installation
add_subdirectory(json)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    "main.cpp"
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)
```

I tried this (ugly) solution, but it did not work:

```
get_target_property(_opt_old nlohmann_json INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS)
string(REPLACE "gnu++11" "c++2a" _opt_new "${_opt_old}")
set_target_properties(nlohmann_json PROPERTIES INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS "${_opt_new}")
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this on CMake 3.17 and nlohmann::json 3.7.3, my `main.cpp` is compiled with only `-std=gnu++2a`.

Comment: I guess the problem is somehow related with `target_compile_features(${NLOHMANN_JSON_TARGET_NAME} INTERFACE cxx_std_11)` line in the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/CMakeLists.txt#L54). Feature `cxx_std_11` [could be translated](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#requiring-language-standards) into `-std=gnu++11` compiler option. Note, that when resolving feature and standard requirements, CMake is unaware of `-std=c++2a` flag added *manually*. I would suggest to remove this flag and see what happens.

Comment: I set this and it worked, but it looks ugly: set_target_properties(nlohmann_json PROPERTIES INTERFACE_COMPILE_FEATURES "") - it's ugly because it potentially empties all the flags apart from the -std

Comment: @Tsyvarev I cannot remove the -std=c++2a from my parent project because my compiler defaults to c++11 otherwise, while I need some of the c++20 features

Comment: "my compiler defaults to c++11 otherwise" - This looks weird as you have `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)` and `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)` which should force CMake to pass appropriate options to compiler for enable `c++20` standard. You do not redefine a compiler in your `CMakeLists.txt`, do you?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes those two set commands are what add "std=c++20". Without this flag the compiler won't use c++20 by default. However, I tried to remove "add_compile_options(-std=c++2a)" only, but nothing changes.

Comment: "but nothing changes." - That is, **without** explicit adding a standard via `add_compile_options` you still have compiler's command line contained **both** `std=c++2a` and `std=gnu++11` flags? Looks like a CMake deficiency.

Comment: @Tsyvarev exactly: "add_compile_options" is something I added afterwards (other than CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD), while trying to propagate/enforce the use of c++20 by the subproject. The effect of it was to just add a second "-std=c++20" flag to the compiler command, yes, but *before* the "-std=gnu++11" flag set by the subproject